# CSS: flex-grow DIV expands on overflow but a scrollarea is needet

Tags: html, css, flexbox

## `Flex-grow` `div` scrollarea?

I'm am trying to create a fullscreen HTML page that fits the viewport without the need of vertical scroll.

The top and bottom `div`s have a fixed height, for example `200px` and `100px`.
The div in between should dynamically fill the gap what I already accomplished using `flex-grow`.

When the central `div` gets filled and starts to overflow it expands and the page does not fit the viewport anymore. I would like that the central `div` instead turns into a scrollable area and keep the fitting height.

### Desired layout:

[image: Layout]

```css
.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top_div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.bottom_div {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.center_div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: cyan;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top_div">
    <h3>Top Div with fixed height, 100px</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="center_div">

    <div style="overflow: hidden">
      <div style="overflow: auto;">
        <!-- Scroll DIV -->
        <h3>Central DIV </h3>
        <h3>Fills the gap between top and bottom div</h3>
        <h3>Should be a scrollarea on overflow</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="bottom_div">
    <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify your overflow. Here you are using `overflow` instead you need to be using `overflow-y: auto`. `overflow-y` tells CSS that you are targeting the vertical axis (up and down) and `auto` says "When the area would normally stretch to make more room, create a scroll bar."
HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top_div">
        <h3>Top Div with fixed height, 100px</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="center_div">

        <div style="overflow: hidden">
            <div style="overflow: auto;">
            <!-- Scroll DIV -->
                <h3>Central DIV </h3>
                <h3>Fills the gap between top and bottom div</h3>
                <h3>Should be a scrollarea on overflow</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="bottom_div">
        <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper, html, body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top_div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.bottom_div {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.center_div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: cyan;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 500px;
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size 10px;
}
```

The only change here is in your .center-div where I added overflow-y and added a height to prevent any of the divs from changing size based on whether or not the .central-div has content.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

Comment: one problem i found with your solution is that now the top and bottom divs are scaled to a minimum without keeping the fixed height i gave them. any ideas for that issue or should i take a different aproach?

Comment: Are they not staying at their respective heights? top div should stay at 100px bottom should be 70px correct? Have you tried making them larger or smaller? It seems to be working for me.https://codepen.io/bbenefield/pen/yXPQYg

Comment: but its not constant. when the central div is empty the top div is way bigger (full 500px i guess) than when wenn the central div is overflown.

Comment: give your central div a height and I think this fixed your problem. https://codepen.io/bbenefield/pen/yXPQYg?editors=1100

Comment: Alright, updated my answer for anyone who might stumble in here. Go ahead and check it as the answer if you would not mind.

Answer (score 2):

Specify `flex-basis: 0` and `min-height: 0` for your `center_div` (default values of them are `auto`), because flex items are not allowed to occupy less than their content by default. This will allow your block to shrink.

Also add `overflow-y: auto` for adding scrollbar to `center_div` when needed.

You can remove some redundant blocks from your markup. Demo:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top_div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
  
.bottom_div {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.center_div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0; /* new */
  min-height: 0; /* new */
  overflow-y: auto; /* new */
  background-color: cyan;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_div">
  <h3>Top Div with fixed height, 100px</h3>
</div>
<div class="center_div">
  <!-- Scroll DIV -->
  <h3>Central DIV </h3>
  <h3>Fills the gap between top and bottom div</h3>
  <h3>Should be a scrollarea on overflow</h3>
</div>
<div class="bottom_div">
  <h3>Bottom Div with fixed height, 70px</h3>
</div>
```

Also consider changing `min-height` to something more than `0` to prevent `center_div` disappearing when body height is very low.